# rails 3, why I can't use command line at ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rubymine, ubuntu-11.10

I am running RubyMine 4 on Ubuntu 11.10, every thing is fine inside RubyMine, I can run the server, develop, etc .. but, when I need to work on the command line, I just can't do anything ..

I cd to my app directory, then I tried to:

```
$ rails s
```

I get:

```
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
```

That's is strange, how come its not installed, while I can work normally in RubyMine IDE !

I needed to use command line to uninstall a gem, to discover that I can't use the command line as it should ..

```
sam@ubuntu:~/Documents/RoR/course_builder$ gem uninstall 'capybara-firebug'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    cannot uninstall, check `gem list -d capybara-firebug`
```

`$ gem list -d` will give me:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
```

no gems there ..

if I type :

```
$ bundle install
```

I get:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:8:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:8
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:11:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:11
    from /usr/bin/bundle:4:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:4
```

although `bundle install` inside RubyMine works fine

so, what I am missing here ?!! why I can't use the command line .. ?

here is my gem environment:

```
RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.10
RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [i686-linux]
INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global
RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin
RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  ruby
  x86-linux
GEM PATHS:
   /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global
GEM CONFIGURATION:
   :update_sources => true
   :verbose => true
   :benchmark => false
   :backtrace => false
   :bulk_threshold => 1000
REMOTE SOURCES:
   http://rubygems.org/
----------------------
IDE: JetBrains RubyMine 4.0.1, build #RM-113.20
OS: Linux 3.0.0-16-generic[i386]
Java: 1.6.0_23-b23
RubyMine SDK Environment:
Sdk: RVM: ruby-1.9.3-p0 [global]
Sdk Version: ver.1.9.3p0 ( revision 33570) p0
Ruby Interpreter: /home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
RVM Sdk: yes, gemset:global
RVM Home: /home/sam/.rvm
Sdk Language Level: 1.9
Sdk Load Path:
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux
     /opt/RubyMine-4.0.1/rubystubs19
Sdk Gem paths: 
     ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bundler/gems
     ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems
Gems used for 'hope':
     xpath (bundled(0.1.4))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/xpath-0.1.4
     rack (1.3.6)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rack-1.3.6
     rspec-expectations (2.7.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rspec-expectations-2.7.0
     rack-mount (bundled(0.8.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3
     rubyzip (bundled(0.9.5))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rubyzip-0.9.5
     bcrypt-ruby (bundled(3.0.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1
     activemodel (bundled(3.1.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.1.0
     client_side_validations (3.1.4)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/client_side_validations-3.1.4
     cocoon (bundled(1.0.15))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/cocoon-1.0.15
     diff-lcs (1.1.3)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/diff-lcs-1.1.3
     sprockets (2.0.3)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/sprockets-2.0.3
     rack-ssl (1.3.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rack-ssl-1.3.2
     simple_form (1.5.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/simple_form-1.5.2
     thor (bundled(0.14.6))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.14.6
     rdoc (3.12)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rdoc-3.12
     rubyzip (bundled(0.9.6.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rubyzip-0.9.6.1
     foreigner (1.1.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/foreigner-1.1.1
     mocha (bundled(0.10.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mocha-0.10.3
     mime-types (bundled(1.17.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mime-types-1.17.2
     treetop (bundled(1.4.10))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/treetop-1.4.10
     therubyracer (bundled(0.9.9))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.9.9
     kaminari (bundled(0.13.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/kaminari-0.13.0
     selenium-webdriver (bundled(2.17.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.17.0
     coffee-script (2.2.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0
     sass (bundled(3.1.14))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.14
     mail (bundled(2.3.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.3.0
     rack-mount (0.8.3)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3
     will_paginate (bundled(3.0.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/will_paginate-3.0.3
     i18n (0.6.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/i18n-0.6.0
     rspec-mocks (bundled(2.7.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-mocks-2.7.0
     ansi (bundled(1.4.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ansi-1.4.1
     orm_adapter (0.0.6)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/orm_adapter-0.0.6
     rspec-core (2.7.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1
     pg (0.13.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/pg-0.13.2
     metaclass (0.0.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/metaclass-0.0.1
     builder (3.0.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/builder-3.0.0
     execjs (bundled(1.3.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.3.0
     uglifier (bundled(1.2.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-1.2.3
     jquery-rails (bundled(1.0.19))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.19
     rspec-expectations (bundled(2.7.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-expectations-2.7.0
     bundler (1.0.21)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21
     postgres-pr (bundled(0.6.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/postgres-pr-0.6.3
     capybara-firebug (bundled(1.0.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-firebug-1.0.1
     rspec-rails (bundled(2.7.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.7.0
     warden (1.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/warden-1.1.0
     rails (3.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rails-3.1.0
     sass-rails (3.1.5)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/sass-rails-3.1.5
     capybara-firebug (1.0.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/capybara-firebug-1.0.1
     rspec (2.7.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rspec-2.7.0
     actionpack (3.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/actionpack-3.1.0
     rack (bundled(1.3.6))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6
     mime-types (1.17.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/mime-types-1.17.2
     capybara (bundled(1.1.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-1.1.2
     nokogiri (1.5.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0
     rake (0.9.2.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2
     nokogiri (bundled(1.5.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0
     sqlite3 (1.3.5)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5
     actionmailer (bundled(3.1.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.1.0
     therubyracer (0.9.9)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/therubyracer-0.9.9
     metaclass (bundled(0.0.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/metaclass-0.0.1
     launchy (2.0.5)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/launchy-2.0.5
     rack-cache (bundled(1.0.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.0.3
     rdoc (bundled(3.12))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-3.12
     polyglot (0.3.3)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/polyglot-0.3.3
     factory_girl (bundled(2.4.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-2.4.0
     tilt (bundled(1.3.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.3.3
     uglifier (1.2.3)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/uglifier-1.2.3
     rb-fsevent (bundled(0.4.3.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rb-fsevent-0.4.3.1
     uglifier (bundled(1.2.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-1.2.2
     treetop (1.4.10)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/treetop-1.4.10
     warden (bundled(1.1.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.1.0
     coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/coffee-script-source-1.2.0
     execjs (bundled(1.2.13))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.2.13
     guard-spork (bundled(0.5.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/guard-spork-0.5.1
     ffi (1.0.11)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/ffi-1.0.11
     rb-fsevent (bundled(0.9.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.0
     ffi (bundled(1.0.11))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11
     arel (bundled(2.2.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/arel-2.2.1
     guard (bundled(1.0.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/guard-1.0.0
     kaminari (0.13.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/kaminari-0.13.0
     validate_url (bundled(0.2.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/validate_url-0.2.0
     coffee-rails (3.1.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/coffee-rails-3.1.1
     actionmailer (3.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/actionmailer-3.1.0
     turn (bundled(0.9.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/turn-0.9.2
     capybara-webkit (bundled(0.9.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.9.0
     coffee-rails (bundled(3.1.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.1.1
     rspec-mocks (2.7.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rspec-mocks-2.7.0
     childprocess (bundled(0.3.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/childprocess-0.3.1
     sprockets (bundled(2.0.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.0.3
     execjs (1.3.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/execjs-1.3.0
     tilt (1.3.3)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/tilt-1.3.3
     rspec (bundled(2.7.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-2.7.0
     spork (bundled(0.9.0.rc9))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9
     rspec-rails (2.7.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rspec-rails-2.7.0
     haml (bundled(3.1.4))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.1.4
     rake (bundled(0.9.2.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2
     tzinfo (0.3.31)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/tzinfo-0.3.31
     bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1
     pg (bundled(0.13.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.13.2
     actionpack (bundled(3.1.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0
     devise (bundled(1.5.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.5.2
     capybara-webkit (bundled(0.8.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.8.0
     database_cleaner (0.7.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/database_cleaner-0.7.1
     foreigner (bundled(1.1.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/foreigner-1.1.1
     addressable (bundled(2.2.6))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/addressable-2.2.6
     selenium-webdriver (bundled(2.19.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0
     rspec-core (bundled(2.7.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1
     simple_form (bundled(1.5.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/simple_form-1.5.2
     builder (bundled(3.0.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/builder-3.0.0
     erubis (bundled(2.7.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/erubis-2.7.0
     orm_adapter (bundled(0.0.6))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/orm_adapter-0.0.6
     validate_url (0.2.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/validate_url-0.2.0
     cocoon (1.0.15)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/cocoon-1.0.15
     addressable (2.2.6)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/addressable-2.2.6
     haml (3.1.4)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/haml-3.1.4
     sass (bundled(3.1.12))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.12
     hike (1.2.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/hike-1.2.1
     libv8 (bundled(3.3.10.4))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4-x86-linux
     coffee-script-source (bundled(1.2.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-source-1.2.0
     erubis (2.7.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/erubis-2.7.0
     spork (bundled(1.0.0rc2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc2
     factory_girl_rails (bundled(1.5.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl_rails-1.5.0
     capybara (1.1.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/capybara-1.1.2
     tzinfo (bundled(0.3.31))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tzinfo-0.3.31
     mocha (bundled(0.10.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mocha-0.10.1
     jquery-rails (1.0.19)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.19
     json (1.6.5)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/json-1.6.5
     guard (bundled(0.10.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/guard-0.10.0
     factory_girl (bundled(2.5.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-2.5.1
     factory_girl_rails (bundled(1.6.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl_rails-1.6.0
     hike (bundled(1.2.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/hike-1.2.1
     rack-cache (1.0.3)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rack-cache-1.0.3
     activeresource (3.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/activeresource-3.1.0
     railties (bundled(3.1.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0
     libv8 (3.3.10.4)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4-x86-linux
     rack-test (bundled(0.6.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-test-0.6.1
     sass-rails (bundled(3.1.5))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.1.5
     i18n (bundled(0.6.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.0
     multi_json (1.0.4)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/multi_json-1.0.4
     sqlite3 (bundled(1.3.5))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5
     xpath (0.1.4)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/xpath-0.1.4
     coffee-script (bundled(2.2.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0
     activemodel (3.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/activemodel-3.1.0
     turn (bundled(0.8.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/turn-0.8.3
     activesupport (3.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/activesupport-3.1.0
     will_paginate (bundled(3.0.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/will_paginate-3.0.2
     devise (1.5.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/devise-1.5.2
     ansi (bundled(1.4.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ansi-1.4.2
     polyglot (bundled(0.3.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.3
     json (bundled(1.6.5))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.5
     mail (2.3.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/mail-2.3.0
     client_side_validations (bundled(3.1.4))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/client_side_validations-3.1.4
     activerecord (3.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/activerecord-3.1.0
     rack-ssl (bundled(1.3.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-ssl-1.3.2
     guard-spork (bundled(0.5.2))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/guard-spork-0.5.2
     childprocess (bundled(0.3.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/childprocess-0.3.0
     rack-test (0.6.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/rack-test-0.6.1
     activerecord (bundled(3.1.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0
     arel (2.2.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/arel-2.2.1
     activesupport (bundled(3.1.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0
     rails (bundled(3.1.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-3.1.0
     activeresource (bundled(3.1.0))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeresource-3.1.0
     launchy (bundled(2.0.5))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/launchy-2.0.5
     railties (3.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/railties-3.1.0
     ansi (1.4.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/ansi-1.4.2
     multi_json (bundled(1.0.4))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/multi_json-1.0.4
     thor (0.14.6)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/thor-0.14.6
     database_cleaner (bundled(0.7.1))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/database_cleaner-0.7.1
     diff-lcs (bundled(1.1.3))
         ~/Documents/RoR/course_builder/CDPATH=/ruby/1.9.1/gems/diff-lcs-1.1.3
```

**EDIT**

If I type rvm, I get:

> ```
>     = rvm
>
>     * http://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm
>
>     == DESCRIPTION:
>
>     RVM is the Ruby enVironment Manager (rvm).
>     It manages Ruby application environments and switching between them.
>
>     == Usage
>
>       rvm [Flags] [Options] Action [Implementation[,Implementation[,...]]
>
>     == Flags
>
>       --default     - with 'rvm use X', sets the default ruby for new shells to X.
>       --debug       - Toggle debug mode on for very verbose output.
>       --trace       - Toggle trace mode on to see EVERYTHING rvm is doing.
>       --force       - Force install, removes old install & source before install.
>
> ....
>
>     == Contributions:
>
>       Any and all contributions offered in any form, past present or future, to the
>       RVM project are understood to be in complete agreement and acceptance with the
>       Apache Licence v2.0.
>
>     == INSTALL:
>
>     See http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/
>
>     or just use:
>
>         bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
>
>     == LICENSE:
>
>     Copyright (c) 2009-2011 Wayne E. Seguin
>
>     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
>     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
>     You may obtain a copy of the License at
>
>         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
>
>     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
>     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
>     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
>     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
>     limitations under the License.
> ```

**if I type ruby -v**

```
sam@ubuntu:~/Documents/RoR/course_builder$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
```

Comment: What does typing "rvm" do? How about ruby -v?

Comment: please see the edit above for rvm result, ruby -v result

Comment: Did you actually install rvm? Did you `rvm use xxxx` on the command line to pick your Ruby and gemset?

Comment: Could you also post your .bashrc or .bash_profile (if you changed them)?

Comment: Thanks Dave, I used rvm use to pick the ruby version & gemset, and it worked fine .. I am sorry, but, I am newbie to rvm ..

Comment: Hello Dave, could you please add your comments as an Answer so that I can accept it, thanks

Comment: Interesting, I am having the same problem, and I do not even use RVM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe your rvm has been setup correctly. For sake of simplicity, let's start from the beginning following the instructions here:

http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

Install in command line.

```
user$ bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
```

Open your .bashrc folder in your home directory.

```
user$ vim .bashrc
```

Edit and add:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

Source your .bashrc file and close the terminal

```
user$ source ~/.bashrc
user$ exit
```

Reopen terminal and check if rvm is working.

```
user$ type rvm | head -1
```

If it returns

```
rvm is a function
```

We're good. Check if you have all of the prerequisites:

```
rvm requirements
```

Install as necessary. Pick your favorite flavor of ruby (it seems like it is 1.8.7, if so follow the exact command or replace it with your choice).

```
rvm install 1.8.7
```

When its done,

```
rvm use 1.8.7 --default
```

If this didn't work, please update post by running

```
which ruby
```

Comment: Thanks Sunny, I've fixed the problem, I should use the gemset first before I do anything! sorry, but, I am newbie to RVM ..

Answer (score 0):

Try running `/bin/bash --login` in your command line before doing any `rails`-related stuff. If it works, do this again in each new command line you open.